# React Native FlatList with alternate rows having different number of columns

Tags: react-native, flexbox

i want to have a FlatList which renders a single item on odd rows and 2 items on even rows [image: image layout]

Is it possible to achieve this layout.
I apologize I do not have code for it up yet.

Answer (score 1):

FlatList has a `renderItem` prop which is a function. That function is called for each item which FlatList draws. You have to pass that function to FlatList. In that function, you return the View to be drawn for each item. So you can return whatever you want to draw for a particular row.

The `renderItem` function passes the index of the item as the second argument. In your case you can use that argument to draw 1 or two columns (or whatever else you might want to draw).

```
<FlatList
  data={[{key: 'a', title: 'single column stuff' }, {key: 'b', col1: 'col1 text', col2: 'col2 text'}]}
  renderItem={(item, index) => {
    if(index % 2 === 0) {
      return <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <View style={{flex: 1}}><Text> {item.col1} </Text></View>
        <View style={{flex: 1}}><Text> {item.col2} </Text></View>
      </View>
    } else {
      return <View style={{flex: 1}}><Text> {item.title} </Text></View>
    }
  }}

/>
```

Comment: The problem Im facing is that content in each container is dependent on the item in the list and is not static text. So in this example <Text>Col 2 </Text> would actually have to be content of the next item which wouldn't me present in that scope at that time. Appreciate your help though

Comment: @melroyd16 i edited Mukesh's answer. Now it should suit your needs

Comment: Got it. so I got to transform my data structure from a regular 1D array to an array as described in the example and club 2 items together for the row with 2 columns

Comment: This means we need to modify the data.

Answer (score -1):

```
<FlatList
data={itemArray}
numColumns={2}
showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
renderItem={({item, index}) => {
let singleItem = itemArray?.length - 1 === index;
return <View><Text>{signleItem}</Text></View>}/>
```